# kdb q+ how do I get check any change in value of a column and return if they are different

Tags: kdb

KDB novice here,
consider a KDB table

| Date | ID | NAME | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | ABC | 23000 |
| 2024-01-01 | 2 | XYZ | 14000 |
| 2024-01-02 | 1 | ABC | 23500 |
| 2024-01-02 | 2 | XYZ | 14000 |
| 2024-01-03 | 1 | ABC | 1400 |
| 2024-01-03 | 2 | XYZ | 23000 |
| 2024-01-04 | 1 | ABC | 1400 |
| 2024-01-04 | 2 | XYZ | 23000 |
| 2024-01-07 | 1 | ABC | 1000 |
| 2024-01-07 | 2 | XYZ | 3000 |

Given the table above I would like a kdb q+ query to compare today against previous day based on ID and NAME and return only rows where balance has changed.

Here, if i run on 2nd then i should get only

| Date | ID | NAME | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-02 | 1 | ABC | 23500 |

On 7th I should get

| Date | ID | NAME | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-07 | 1 | ABC | 1000 |
| 2024-01-07 | 2 | XYZ | 3000 |

I need it to also compare string column values and return them as well if it is not the same as previous day. previous day can be 1 day or 2-3 days prior.

Comment: Please include code to create your sample data set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `name` actually uniquely defined by `id`? In that case this should work:

```
q)t:([]date:2024.01.01 2024.01.01 2024.01.02 2024.01.02 2024.01.03 2024.01.03 2024.01.04 2024.01.04 2024.01.07 2024.01.07;id:10#1 2;name:10#`ABC`XYZ;balance:23000 14000 23500 14000 1400 23000 1400 23000 1000 3000)
q)select from t where (differ;balance)fby id,date=2024.01.02
date       id name balance
--------------------------
2024.01.02 1  ABC  23500
q)select from t where (differ;balance)fby id,date=2024.01.07
date       id name balance
--------------------------
2024.01.07 1  ABC  1000
2024.01.07 2  XYZ  3000
```

If there were rows with the same `id` but with different name, the `fby` should be changed to `([]id;name)` instead of just `id`.

See: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fby/